# Why cant I find startStateNotifications function on the ble object of the cordova-plugin-ble-central plugin?

Tags: cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using phonegap/cordova and the cordova-plugin-ble-central plugin for bluetoothLE connection.

So the ble object does exist and works fine I can scan, connect and check if bluetooth is enabled.

But if I want to hook in a callback for the case the bluetooth module becomes disable from outside the App, it appears that the proper function as the documentation would tell, does not exist...

I'm using

> ble.startStateNotifications(onStateChange, notificationFail);

And what I get is this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: ble.startStateNotifications is not a function"

What might be the Issue here?

I'm testing using the Phonegap app on Android.

In the open issues of the plugin I can find nothing like that - so most propably it works fine for other people - so it is most probably my own fault^^. But I have no idea what that could be :-(

Comment: Are you sure that 'startStateNotifications' is the name of an existing function ? There may be a typo, or this function was replaced by a new one ?

Comment: yes because here are the docs: https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#startstatenotifications
and I also copy and pasted the exact name from the doc xD

Comment: Well it seems correct. Can you put your real code (not all but this part) in your question ? Or is the quote actually your exact code ?

Comment: Hi Tim!
Sorry for leaving out the Problem for some time now. Yhea the line is part of the real code.

Comment: Harr, why cannot I edit my comment... here the second Part: I will edit the Question when I managed create a sample application exclusivly using this plugin and this function.